# Accessing source sets with kotlin-dsl for gradle

Tags: gradle, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

How do I convert the following groovy snippet

```
URL[] urls = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath.files.collect {
    it.toURI().toURL()
}
```

to kotlin-dsl? Particularly the property sourceSets doesn't seem to available and fails to compile.

How do I access the sourceSets in a task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `sourceSet` for the `runtimeClasspath`. The `classpath` is different to the `sourceSet`. But if you are interested in getting e.g. the `main-sourceset` of a project with the kotlin-dsl, here is a snippet:

```
java {
    val files: Set<File> = sourceSets["main"].java.srcDirs
    println(files)
}
```

Accessing the sourceSet from a task

```
task("hello-src-set") {
    val files: Set<File> = java.sourceSets["main"].java.srcDirs
    println(files)
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this in a task? currently sourceSets variable doesn't seem to in scope of my the task I'm working on

Comment: I updated you the answer to access the sourceset from a task

Comment: seems the answer is correct, but instead of `java.sourceSets`, I need to access them via the `the<JavaPluginConvention>().sourceSets` method instead. Please kindly revise so I could accept! Thanks.

Comment: Why does it complain when using `java.sourceSets["main"]...` because I tried the `hello-src-set` task in my project and it works fine. Your solution btw also works.

Comment: seems like an IDE issue. Accepting!